# esp32 e-paper driver not working

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, display

I am trying to setup waveshare 7.5 display (Waveshare_7_5) with esp32 e-paper driver using [ESP32-e-Paper-Weather-Display](https://github.com/G6EJD/ESP32-e-Paper-Weather-Display)

My code is here https://pastebin.com/raw/2zQDe9a9, have corresponding `owm_credentials.h`, installed `GxEPD2` & `U8g2_for_Adafruit_GFX`

Code gets uploaded to esp32 driver board using Arduino IDE, but Getting following in serial monitor & no display on e-paper

```
Busy Timeout!
Busy Timeout!
Busy Timeout!
Busy Timeout!
Entering 1675-secs of sleep time
Awake for : 44.518-secs
Starting deep-sleep period...
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: your question is about interfacing the e-paper display ... why does your program contain code relating to weather and to wifi? ... reduce the code to minimum required to display something on the e-paper display

Comment: Maybe I have the same problem on a ESP32 NodeMCU with a waveshare 1.54 inch display. Did you solve the problem?